# Connman switch back to prefered network when back online

Tags: networking, embedded-linux, failover, connman

I would like to use ConnMan in an embedded system.
It seems that it provides most of the features I'm looking for including 3G and VPN management.

But after some research it seems that there is maybe one missing point in it.
Let say I have the following setup :

- Ethernet connection as preferred connection
- 3/4G connection as backup/failover connection

My Ethernet is always on and dhcp server is properly providing IP, cable is still plugged in,  and power on the line is still there but sometimes the internet connectivity is lost.
So in that case I'll switch to my 3G connection. But then as soon as possible, when connectivity is back online via the ethernet, I want to switch  back to it for performance and cost reason.

Is this supported by default, or is there a way to configure it that way ?

I found [this post](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.linux.network.connman/10238) which seems to say that it was not supported at that time, since there is no periodic check (February 2013).
And also from the [documentation](https://01.org/connman/documentation)  :

> Autoconnecting
>
> Favorite (saved) networks that have autoconnect enabled are considered
>   when autoconnecting services. These services are marked with '*' and
>   'A' in connmanctl, respectively. By default ConnMan autoconnects these
>   in the order they are shown in the list of services until one of them
>   gets connected. After that the autoconnected service is in use and
>   ConnMan won't select a new one until the network goes out of range.
>   When the service goes out of range or gets disconnected from the
>   network infrastructure side, autoconnect is re-run and another
>   favorite autoconnectable service is selected.

Feel free to ask for more informations if this is unclear.

Answer (score 1):

This could be of some help to others, so I'll post here the answer to my own question.

There is no continuous connectivity check. This is only done at the beginning on each available link, or when a link changes state.

So the use case I'm describing is not supported by default.

This could be done externally by having a daemon checking this and posting messages on DBUS or this could be implemented directly in connman.
But this last option is maybe not the best since it's not sure this could be accepted in connman mainline (not everyone want that inside).

We will opt for the external daemon solution and DBus messages.

Comment: Any idea whether the feature requested is available in the latest connman. Is there any open source daemon, to check the connectivity or you have written on your own?